# 404 (Not Found) after DELETE request using fetch

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, rest, fetch

I am calling a DELETE request using fetch. The request is working fine (Status is 200 OK on Postman). However, when redirecting to `'/'` after delete the following error is showing up in my console:

```
script.js:2 DELETE http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)
```

Contents of script.js:

```
function deleteItem(id) {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/items/' + id, {
        method: 'DELETE'
    })
        .then(res => res.text()) // or res.json()
        .then(res => console.log(res));
}
```

(line 2 is the fetch)

These are in the app.js file:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.ejs', {count: items.length, items: items});
    console.log(items);
});

app.delete('/items/:id', urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
    let index = parseInt(req.params.id);
    items.splice(index, 1);

    res.redirect('/');
});
```

I know for sure that the render in get is not working properly because `console.log(items)` is not being executed. I am confused because the redirect in my POST method is working fine.

**Can anybody help me figure out why I am getting this error, please?** I know for sure that the item is being deleted successfully, and when I refresh the page manually, the HTML is naturally loaded with the updated data.

Comment: Don't issue redirects for API requests. Let the client decide what to do after the request completes

Comment: do `res.status(200).json({ message: "whatever" })` instead, this looks like an `API` endpoint, don't do redirects

Comment: Or you can add a conditional checking, to check wether the request is completed, if it is, only then redirect to another page

Comment: So it's always bad practice to do automatic redirects after a request is finished? Because then how will updates made be displayed on the screen?

Comment: Usually it's a front end which will show the update. not the api